# Python concurrent.futures

Tags: python, dictionary, concurrent.futures

I have a multiprocessing code, and each process have to analyse same data differently.

I have implemented:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
   res = executor.map(goal_fcn, p, [global_DataFrame], [global_String])

for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(res):
   fp = res
```

and function:

```
def goal_fcn(x, DataFrame, String):
   return heavy_calculation(x, DataFrame, String)
```

the problem is `goal_fcn` is called only once, while should be multiple time

In debugger, I checked now the variable `p` is looking, and it has multiple columns and rows. Inside `goal_fcn`, variable `x` have only first row - looks good.

But the function is called only once. There is no error, the code just execute next steps.

Even if I modify variable `p = [1,3,4,5]`, and of course code. `goal_fcn` is executed only once

I have to use `map()` because keeping the order between input and output is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`map` works like `zip`. It terminates once at least one input sequence is at its end. Your `[global_DataFrame]` and `[global_String]` lists have one element each, so that is where map ends.

There are two ways around this:

1. Use `itertools.product`. This is the equivalent of running "for all data frames, for all strings, for all p". Something like this:

```py
def goal_fcn(x_DataFrame_String):
    x, DataFrame, String = x_DataFrame_String
    ...

executor.map(goal_fcn, itertools.product(p, [global_DataFrame], [global_String]))
```

2. Bind the fixed arguments instead of abusing the sequence arguments.

```py
def goal_fcn(x, DataFrame, String):
    pass

bound = functools.partial(goal_fcn, DataFrame=global_DataFrame, String=global_String)
executor.map(bound, p)
```